# Error: conversion from ‘’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} requested

Tags: c++, syntax

I have a program to try to solve this Codeforces question -> https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1625/A

However, when I run the code an error pops up.
This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main (){
  int tests;
  string aray[10000];
  cin >> tests;
  for(int a; a < tests; a++){
    int words, letters;
    cin >> words >> letters;
    for(int b; b < words; b++){
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        string binary = bitset<32>(x).to_string;
        aray[b] = binary;
    }
    int zeros, ones, total;
    for(int c; c < 32; c++){
        for(int d; d < words; d++){
            if(aray[d][c] = '0'){
                zeros++;
            }else{
                ones++;
            }
        }
        if(zeros < ones){
            total = total + pow(2, 31-c);
        }
    }
    cout << total;
  }
}
```

I tried searching up solutions, but I just couldn't understand or find any solutions that helped me.
Can you tell me why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks!
I've just started C++ and am not too familiar with syntax.

Comment: the issue is here: "string binary = bitset<32>(x).to_string;", you've forgotten to call the function, it should be "string binary = bitset<32>(x).to_string();"

Comment: This is not the only "issue" here. The first issue would be `for(int a; a < tests; a++){`.

Comment: For future questions it would be really helpful for you to include the line that causes the error. Your compiler tells you that, so please let us know as well. Also: IMO these coding puzzles are not that bad. You just can't do them expecting they'll make you a good **programmer**, instead they just train general logic/problem solving skills - which can also be useful.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I wouldn't place an array of 10000 strings on the stack (`string aray[10000];`). And it's better to use `std::vector<std::string>` anyway.

Comment: The indices in your loops (`a`, `b` etc.) are uninitialized. That's causing UB when using them.

Answer (score 2):

try replacing:

```
string binary = bitset<32>(x).to_string;
```

with:

```
string binary = bitset<32>(x).to_string();
                                       ^^
```